# Update asp.net Xml Sitemap

Tags: asp.net, sitemap, web.sitemap

The project I am working allows users to create pages in a CMS type system.

I would like to use an asp.net sitemap to reference these pages. So when a page is added or moved the Xml sitemap would be updated.

Is this a practical solution and are there any solutions available that work similar to this?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably write your own SiteMapProvider see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178431.aspx that loads from your CMS.